# How does the HX711 circuit work?

Tags: arduino, transistors, capacitor, load-cell

This scheme will be designed for weight scales. Why is there a transistor installed.
And I want to understand why need capacitors and resistors in this circuit. (their purpose)
The documentation does not describe the connection diagram, there is only an example of connecting to a load cell.

[HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The PNP transistor is used by the internal linear regulator. This provides a stable \$V_{DD}\$ and excitation voltage for the IC and bridge respectively.
- The resistors `R1` and `R2` are used to set the feedback for the linear regulator.
- Capacitors `C1` and `C2` are decoupling capacitors for the IC's power supply.
- Capacitor `C3` is decoupling for the internal bandgap reference.
- Resistors `R3`, `R4`, and capacitor `C4` form a differential low pass filter.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer.

Comment: @user10360597 No problem, hope it was useful.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

The external transistor takes the heat generating element of the voltage regulation off the chip. This will help in heat management and, possibly, calibration stability.